# ThenBy() not working under specific conditions

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

Let's say I have a list of a class like this (edited, far more equivalent to the original code):

```
public class Foo
{
    public FooEnum enum;
    public DateTime dt;
    enum FooEnum
    {
        prop1 = 0,
        prop2 = 1
    }
}
```

Now if we have a list of this class, let's call it `_fooList`, and it contains two `Foo` objects, one of which contains `01/01/01` for `dt` and `prop2` for `enum`, and another one with `01/01/01` for `dt` and `prop1` for `enum`, in that order. 
Now, if I `OrderBy` the `DateTime` first, that keeps it the same, but then, when I sort by the `FooEnum`, it STILL stays the same, even though the `Foo` containing `prop1` should be first. Is there any explanation for this?

(Note: this is a REALLY summarized version of my problem).

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: Rather than explain in words what you are doing why not just give us the code so we can reproduce your issue ourselves?

Comment: Umm, I would, but it needs about ~250 lines of supporting code...

Comment: Try making a small repro. Odds are good you will discover what the bug is while you are making the small repro. And if you don't, then you have something that people can actually look at, rather than trying to read your mind.

Comment: @ofstream: Think hard about what you actually need. Like the example given in IronMan84's answer, short and to the point.

Comment: How does those ~250 lines of code affect the sorting?

Comment: @BrianRasmussen They mostly do. You see, there's a few enums, quite a few properties, so on, so forth. But I'm trying to do what EricLippert is saying.

Answer (score 4):

Try this out and tell me if it works:

```
_fooList = _fooList.OrderBy(f => f.someString).ThenBy(f => f.someInt).ToList();
```

Comment: That does work... however some equivalent code doesn't. Odd...

Comment: Are you sure that you're reassigning it to `_fooList`? Why don't you post the LINQ code and we can take a look?

Comment: Yeah, I keep an IOrderedEnumerable, I then do some conditionals (I may need to call sortby/thenby on different properties depending on some other code), but I do reassign it at the end.

Comment: @ofstream then it's not equivalent code :)

Comment: @ofstream: You need to update as you go, if you call _fooList.OrderBy it returns an `OrderedEnumerable` but doesn't change _fooList.

Comment: Took the words right out of my mouth, @DStanley

Comment: @Guvante That just ruins it. IOrderedEnumerable is different IIRC, if you just reassign it to another IEnumerable it won't work for thenBy.